# Uma ajuda para o Stack Overflow em outros idiomas

Tags: debate

O pessoal da matriz [está discutindo a abertura de stacks em espanhol, russo e japonês](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271998/fluent-in-spanish-were-hiring-a-community-manager-for-a-spanish-stack-overflow). Acho que isso reflete o sucesso que o SOpt está mostrando. Do jeito que li, parece que somos um caso de sucesso :)

A questão é, a discussão está acalorada por lá. Não seria interessante darmos um testemunho positivo sobre o nosso estouro de pilha lusófono, para darmos uma mãozinha aos hermanos?

Comment: Obrigado por avisar! Votei e adicionei alguns comentários por lá. ;)

Comment: Tenho pena é dos turcos... Primeira proposta de SO em outro idioma a concluir com sucesso a fase de *commitment*, e estão tendo que esperar bem mais do que os outros... :(

Comment: Os comentários mais votados são aqueles que são contra às novas comunidades. De fato, nós como a primeira experiência nesse sentido devemos sim tentar abrir um pouquinho a cabeça desse povo que tá com medo sei lá do quê.

Comment: _"Post Reopened by Gabe♦"_ hahaha, já fecharam e reabriram várias vezes o tópico

Comment: A discussão tá bombando lá!

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, está. Eu pus uma resposta lá inclusive, e fiquei relativamente ansioso antes de apertar o botão de publicar a resposta, hehehe.. Mas ao que parece correu tudo bem e ainda estou vivo =D

Comment: Não percebo onde está a dificuldade de perceber que os destinatários dos SO__ não são os mesmos do SOen. E se forem, ninguém vai deixar de ir ao SOen. Eu continuo a utilizar o SOen e muitas vezes nem chego a fazer pergunta no SOpt.

Comment: Não achei que haveriam tantos users contrários a criação de SOXX.

Comment: Já está com 17 respostas no tópico lá, wow!! Que movimentação

Comment: Boas as respostas de vocês, pessoal.

Comment: O pior é que os argumentos contra são fortes. Há força na exclusividade do SOen, que vem exatamente da falta de alternativas em outros idiomas para se buscar e contribuir com informação.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O SOpt é incrivelmente bem sucedido. Incontestavelmente. Já falei isso aqui, mas é sempre bom repetir :D

Não há dúvida alguma de que valeu a pena o esforço de encontrar uma nova comunidade, traduzir o site, preparar o lançamento e tudo mais que envolveu o lançamento do SOpt. É isso que esperamos dos novos sites internacionais, que serão basicamente os que o Renan citou (Russo, Japonês e Espanhol, até onde eu saiba).

Estes sites provavelmente serão abertos, salvo algo inesperado e bloqueante. A Stack Exchange escolheu as comunidades "à dedo" e abrir os novos SO faz parte dos planos para o futuro da empresa.

Como há muito mais envolvido na criação de um SO internacional do que na abertura de um site normal (tradução do conteúdo, um CM fluente, entre outras coisas), o processo da Area 51 não é necessariamente seguido à risca. A proposta de um SOru, por exemplo, é mais antiga e maior que a nossa, mas aqui estamos.

Já lidar com a resistência, de dentro e fora da comunidade, é outra coisa. Grande parte de vocês deve se lembrar de alguns anglófonos que diziam que nós "descentralizaríamos conteúdo", e o alguns lusófonos que diziam que nós "não tínhamos razão para uma comunidade separada". O SOpt superou esses torradores de paciência e acho uma **excelente** ideia fazermos de tudo para que os próximos não precisem lidar com isso.

Contar, espalhar, apoiar essas novas propostas faz muito bem à elas, e à comunidade do Stack Exchange em geral. O [Jay](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14/jaydles) ficou muito contente com o post do Renan no MSO. É o tipo de coisa que tem muito peso vindo de alguém de *dentro* do projeto, ao invés da companhia.

Vocês têm meu apoio!